# Arduino, code hangs in weird way when a function is invoked

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt

I have the following code behaving in a weird way, when I make a method call

```
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <cppQueue.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

typedef struct Diagnostic {
String entityName;
uint16_t pin;
} Diag;
// Global setup
cppQueue q(sizeof(Diag *), 10, FIFO, false);
int ctr = 0;
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// Add to queue

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(2000);                       // wait for a second
  Serial.println("After high");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second

  // Critical Section

  Diag d;
  Serial.println("String assignment");
  d.entityName = "Front Door";
  d.pin = LED_BUILTIN;
  d_ptr = &d;
  Serial.println("Enqueuing one");
  q.push(&d);
  Serial.println("Enqueued one");
  Serial.println(freeMemory());
  //q.pop(&d);
  //Serial.println("Dequeued one" + d.entityName);
  DequeueIsr();
  //Serial.println("Atomic block");
  //Serial.println(q.getCount());

  //Serial.println("Loop end");
}

 void DequeueIsr() {
   Diag di;

   if (!q.isEmpty())
   {
      Serial.println("Queue not empty");
      q.pop(&di);
      Serial.println("Dequeued one" + di.entityName);
      Serial.println(freeMemory());
   }   
 }
```

Whenever I try to pop my object in the DequeueIsr function, the code hangs after 2 or 3 iterations, there is no output on the serial monitor after that. If I just copy the code in the Dequeue method and run it in the main loop it works, it doesn't get stuck. Also this happens when I work with strings, if I remove the entityName field from Diag, it works inside the method.
Am I missing something crucial ?

What I really wanted to do was, dequeue the queue using an interrupt method using the TimerOne library. I have removed all timer related code and even a simple method call isn't working.

Comment: How much debugging did you do and what were the insights it yielded? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The Serial.printlns are the only thing helping me here, do you have any other way to debug ? Also when you say insights I mentioned above how the code just works when I remove the code from the Dequeue method and paste it in the loop() function. I am not doing any memory allocations, also I checked the stack memory, it reports 1684 in the second iteration before it gets stuck.

Comment: I would guess that the optimiser is destroying `d` before calling `DequeueIsr` resulting in a dangling pointer in your queue

Comment: Don't know much about the cppQueue, but in normal C++ `q.push(&d)` would be pretty odd - `d` is not dynamically allocated and will go out of scope at the end of `loop()` - if you're lucky `d` will always be the same (which is probably not what you want anyway).

Comment: Here is the official example https://github.com/SMFSW/Queue/blob/master/examples/SimpleQueue/SimpleQueue.ino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cppQueue` copies objects using [`memcpy`](https://github.com/SMFSW/Queue/blob/711b832c8f75477e8a37b9d1ec2fb5dc72f38055/src/cppQueue.cpp#L76) so it only works with trivially copyable objects, `String` is not trivially copyable so your code has undefined behaviour

Comment: https://github.com/SMFSW/Queue/blob/master/examples/PointersQueue/PointersQueue.ino The example here from the official repo is an example with String*, also taking the example code if I put it in a separate function, it works. Why is that so ?

Comment: That example is storing pointers to items in the array `strings` not local objects (note that `q.push(&pStr)` is passing a pointer to a pointer)

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now